# Excel VBA: Count number of unique categories for ID-numbers

Tags: vba, excel

I have ID-numbers in first column and technological categories in the second column.

Data sample look like this;

```html
<table style="border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0"><tr><th style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:inherit;vertical-align:top">ID</th><th style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:black;vertical-align:top">Tech-category</th></tr><tr><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:black;vertical-align:top">SA091</td><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:black;vertical-align:top">H4</td></tr><tr><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:black;vertical-align:top">SA091</td><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:black;vertical-align:top">H3</td></tr><tr><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:black;vertical-align:top">SA091</td><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:black;vertical-align:top">H2</td></tr><tr><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:black;vertical-align:top">EP82</td><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:black;vertical-align:top">K2</td></tr><tr><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:black;vertical-align:top">EP82</td><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:black;vertical-align:top">K2</td></tr><tr><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:black;vertical-align:top">EP82</td><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:black;vertical-align:top">H4</td></tr><tr><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:black;vertical-align:top">EP93</td><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:black;vertical-align:top">T0</td></tr><tr><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:black;vertical-align:top">EP93</td><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:black;vertical-align:top">T0</td></tr><tr><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:black;vertical-align:top">TB99</td><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:black;vertical-align:top">Y2</td></tr></table>
```

and I want to count the number of Tech-categories per ID and output only one result per ID. Make the result look like this;

```html
<table style="border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0"><tr><th style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:black">Result</th><th style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:black">n-Tech categories</th></tr><tr><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:black">SA091</td><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:black">3</td></tr><tr><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:black">EP82</td><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:black">2</td></tr><tr><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:black;vertical-align:top">EP93</td><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:black;vertical-align:top">1</td></tr><tr><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:black;vertical-align:top">TB99</td><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:black;vertical-align:top">1</td></tr></table>
```

I am new to VBA and tried to make the Function nTechAreas with loops and If-statements.

```
Function nTechAreas(key As String, key_array As Range, codes As Range) As Integer
    Dim n As Range
    For i = 1 To key_array.Height
        If key_array(i) = key Then
            If IsNotInArray(codes(i), n) Then
                n(i) = codes.Value
            End If
        End If
    Next i
    nTechAreas = n.Length
End Function

Function IsNotInArray(str As String, arr As Variant) As Boolean
    IsNotInArray = Not ((UBound(Filter(arr, str)) > -1))
End Function
```

However, I can not get it to work. Moreover, I also think there probably exists a much easier/elegant/nicer way off dealing data in Excel VBA. Hence, I tried to use AutoFilter() but havent got that to work aswell.

```
Function nTech(key As String) As Integer

this.Sheets(13).Activate
ActiveSheet.Range("A:G").Select
Selection.AutoFilter Gield:=1, Critera1:=key

End Function
```

Help would be much appriciated.

Comment: Use a dictionary instead.  I'll have a look

Comment: =COUNTIF ought to do what you want surely?

Comment: @HarassedDad  it's counting unique adjacent data, not occurances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a dictionary of dictionaries. Writing result out next to values read in.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub testing()
    Dim arr(), i As Long, dict
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    With ActiveSheet
        arr() = .Range("A2:B10").Value
        For i = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
            If Not dict.Exists(arr(i, 1)) Then
                dict.Add arr(i, 1), CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
                dict(arr(i, 1)).Add arr(i, 2), 1
             Else
                If Not dict(arr(i, 1)).Exists(arr(i, 2)) Then
                    dict(arr(i, 1)).Add arr(i, 2), 1
                Else
                    dict(arr(i, 1))(arr(i, 2)) = dict(arr(i, 1))(arr(i, 2)) + 1
                End If
            End If
        Next i
        Dim key As Variant
        i = 1
        For Each key In dict.keys
            i = i + 1
            .Cells(i, 3) = key
            .Cells(i, 4) = dict(key).Count
        Next key
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Good solution :o)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this.  Not sure it's the best method, just had a play

```
Sub uniques()

Dim dicCodes As New Scripting.Dictionary
Dim dicContents As Scripting.Dictionary
Dim rngCodes As Range
Dim rngInspect As Range

Set rngCodes = Range("a1:a10")

For Each rngInspect In rngCodes.Cells

    If dicCodes.Exists(rngInspect.Value) Then

        Set dicContents = dicCodes(rngInspect.Value)
        If dicContents.Exists(rngInspect.Offset(0, 1).Value) Then
            dicContents(rngInspect.Offset(0, 1).Value) = _
                dicContents(rngInspect.Offset(0, 1).Value) + 1
        Else
            dicContents.Add rngInspect.Offset(0, 1).Value, 1
        End If

    Else

        Set dicContents = New Scripting.Dictionary
        dicContents.Add rngInspect.Offset(0, 1).Value, 1
        dicCodes.Add rngInspect.Value, dicContents

    End If

Next rngInspect

Dim lngOutput As Long
Dim lngOutputInner As Long

For lngOutput = 0 To dicCodes.Count - 1

    For lngOutputInner = 0 To dicCodes.Items()(lngOutput).Count - 1

        Debug.Print dicCodes.Keys()(lngOutput), _
                    dicCodes.Items()(lngOutput).Keys()(lngOutputInner), _
                    dicCodes.Items()(lngOutput).Items()(lngOutputInner)

    Next lngOutputInner

Next lngOutput

End Sub
```